# Iterate TreeSet of TreeMaps - Get common keys from list of TreeMaps

Tags: java, key, treemap, treeset

Hi I'm trying to get the common keys from a TreeSet of TreeMaps:

Ultimately I want to have FinalDocList (a list of String) that contains all the common Keys in the Set of TreeMap(Key, Values).

I tried to iterate the TreeSet but I got error that iterator cannot use the keySet() method. Can anyone help to guide me through this? Many thanks.

```
    TreeSet<String>FinalDocList = new TreeSet<String>();

    Iterator<TreeMap<String, Double>> iterator = queryMapList.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) 
    {
        <String> keys1 = iterator.keySet();
        FinalDocList.retainAll(keys1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(TreeMap<String, Double> map : queryMapList)
{
    for(String s : map.keySet()
        FinalDocList.add(s);
}
```

Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Set<Map> setOfMaps = new HashSet();
    Set finalDocList = null;
    for (Map m : setOfMaps) {
        if (finalDocList == null) {
            finalDocList = m.keySet();
        } else {
            finalDocList.retainAll(m.keySet());
        }
    }
```